# Is there a list of all default python packages in ArcGIS Pro?

Tags: python, arcgis-pro, installation

I'm specifically looking for something with a short description of each package. Many packages don't even have a description and you need to google them. I'd love to have a search function that also looked at the description of each package instead of just its name, so that I could find a package that does what I need more readily.

Answer (score 0):

In the ArcGIS (or ArcGIS Pro) Python window use help() to display information about the library in question.
For example `help(arcpy)` returns a heap of text about arcpy and each tool available in arcpy, the tool parameters, data type requirements, and outputs.  This will work for any library that the developer has built with help text.

Similarly you can limit your help request to specific classes, methods, or functions in a library.  For example `help(arcpy.da)`

Comment: Although this is a useful approach to getting help on ArcPy, or really most Python packages, it doesn't help answer the question.